# Call kit identification

Tags: ios, callkit

First we are receiving 160K data from the server
Then we are trying to insert this 160k data directly to CallKit but we are getting this error :

```
com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager Code=2
CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerErrorLoadingInterrupted
```

Then we tried 30K data to insert and this time it was successful.

Our problem is we can not insert more than 30K, for this reason, we can not use the remaining 120K.

How can we solve this issue ?

This is my extension code:

```
@interface CallDirectoryHandler () <CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate>
@end

@implementation CallDirectoryHandler

- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
    context.delegate = self;

    if (![self addIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:context]) {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"CallDirectoryHandler" code:2 userInfo:nil];
        [context cancelRequestWithError:error];
        return;
    }

    [context completeRequestWithCompletionHandler:nil];
 }

- (BOOL)addIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {

    NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:SharedUserDefaultsSuiteName];
    containerURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:callDirectoryPathComponent];

    NSURL *containerURLForCallerIDFounded = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:SharedUserDefaultsSuiteName];
    containerURLForCallerIDFounded = [containerURLForCallerIDFounded URLByAppendingPathComponent:callDirectorySolvedCallerIDPathComponent];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictFromFile1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:containerURL.path];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictFromFile2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:containerURLForCallerIDFounded.path];
    if (dictFromFile2.count > 0) {
        [dictFromFile1 addEntriesFromDictionary:dictFromFile2];
    }
    if (dictFromFile1.count == 0) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSArray *sortedArray = [[dictFromFile1 allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(
                                                                                       NSString *string1,
                                                                                       NSString *string2) {
        return [string1 compare: string2 options: NSNumericSearch];
    }];

    for (int i=0; i<sortedArray.count; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *number = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *name = dictFromFile1[number];
            if (number && [number isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] &&
                name && [name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumber = [number longLongValue];
                [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:name];
            }
            number = nil;
            name = nil;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate

- (void)requestFailedForExtensionContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)extensionContext withError:(NSError *)error {
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your CallKit extension?  Specifically, are you using an auto release pool and batching your insertions?  Extensions have lower memory quotas and it is easy to exceed these and have your extension terminated. Check the device console. Filter on your extension bundle and also look for messages from `com.apple.callkit`

Comment: Hi, @Paulw11 I added extension code.

Comment: I would suggest you try splitting the loading into blocks of 10,000 with to give a chance for the auto release pool to free memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you break you load up into blocks with the `@autoreleasepool` to reduce your memory consumption; extensions have a lower memory quota than apps and will be terminated if they exceed it.

Something like:

```
int offset = 0

int blockSize = 100

while offset < sortedArray.count {
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i=offset; i < min(sortedArray.count, offset+blockSize); i++) {
            NSString *number = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *name = dictFromFile1[number];
            if (number && [number isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] &&
            name && [name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumber = [number longLongValue];
                [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:name];
            }
            number = nil;
            name = nil;
        }
        offset += blockSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the device console logs to see if there is more information?

Comment: You would probably also be better off doing as much processing in your app as you can - Rather than having to merge and sort the numbers in your extension, do this in your app and just put the sorted array into your plist file

Comment: Also, I checked my code - try a block size of 100 rather than 10,000

Comment: I sorted number on app and block size set 100 but same error.

Comment: You may just have hit a limit, Although I load over 45000 numbers. You need to look for clues in the device console logs

Comment: Thanks for advice. I resolved issue. I solved problem by reading line by line. I added 160k number.

Comment: Yes. I had to make a similar change to my app. I was using Core Data but now I use a simple text file